# If condition to return multiple data type

Tags: hana

I have a column with values:

```
10
20
30
```

I declared this column as `nvarchar`. Now I wanted a calculated column / field where `if column > 0 then column * 10 else column`.

The desired output is:

```
100
200
300
```

I tried if and it didn't work.

Comment: “It didn’t work” gives nothing to work with. What error message did you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN column > 0 THEN column*10 ELSE column END
```

See https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20a4389775191014b5a6bf2ccc0df2ed.html